# python array challenge

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array: `[[0,10,20],[1,15,25],[2,20,40]]`

`0, 1, 2` would be ids and `10,20` `15,25` `20,40` would be their respective range.

So, I need to figure out the ranges and which ids has which range.

Each id would represent a flashlight, and each one has its own range, I need this to figure out which areas are being illuminated by which flashlights.

I don't know if was clear enough, so here is what I expect to be returned from the code:

```
[
 [0],[10,15],
 [0,1],[15,20],
 [1,2],[20,25],
 [2], [25,40]
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any attempts on this challenge so far?

Comment: I'm confused about exactly what you need to do.  What does the output represent?  Also, do you need to have the 0, 1, 2 indexes inside the array?  You can index the ranges with those numbers already without having them there.

Comment: I will edit to explain better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the real line must be segmented:

```
min_boundaries = set(min for id, min, max in orig)
max_boundaries = set(max for id, min, max in orig)
segment_boundaries = sorted(list(min_boundaries | max_boundaries))
```

Then, for each segment, check which lights illuminate that segment. A point in the middle of the segment is enough:

```
result = []
old_boundary = segment_boundaries[0]
for boundary in segment_boundaries[1:]:
    bounds = [old_boundary, boundary]
    middle = (old_boundary + boundary) / 2
    ids = [id for id, min, max in orig if min < middle < max]
    result.append(ids)
    result.append(bounds)
    old_boundary = boundary
```

Answer (score 0):

With some changes in the data structure here is the simple solution:

```
adict = {0: [10, 20], 1: [15, 25], 2: [20, 40]}
data = [(10, 15), (15, 20), (20, 25), (25, 40)]

# This will check the membership 
# in_([3,4], [2,3]) returns True
def in_(val1 , val2):
    return val2[0] >= val1[0] and val2[1] <= val1[1]


res = {}
for each in keys:
    for key in adict.keys():
        if in_(adict[key], each):
            res.setdefault(each, []).append(key)
```

O/P

```
>>>res
{(10, 15): [0], (15, 20): [0, 1], (25, 40): [2], (20, 25): [1, 2]}
```